# html for mobile, page resizes and scroll appears after page loads

Tags: html, mobile, resize, scroll

I am trying to make a responsive website, to work for mobiles too. My problem is when i'm trying to enter the site on my phone, it looks ok till the page loads, after that the page resizes making itself bigger and scroll apears on both width and height.

Is there something i could add to make it take the size of the screen?
Thank you in advance, Daniel!

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the page width to 100%

body{
   width:100%;
   }

Answer (score 0):

Without the source code we cannot know why your website does not fit the screen.
Try to see something in your CSS like

```
@media (max-width: 640px) {
  body {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

More css style from [alsacreations](http://www.alsacreations.com/astuce/lire/1177-une-feuille-de-styles-de-base-pour-le-web-mobile.html)

```
@media (max-width: 640px) {

 /* passer tous les éléments de largeur fixe en largeur automatique */
 body, element1, element2 {
   width: auto;
   margin: auto;
   padding: auto;
 }

 /* fixer une largeur maximale  de 100 % aux éléments potentiellement problématiques */
 img, table, td, blockquote, code, pre, textarea, input, iframe, object, embed, video {
   max-width: 100%;
 }
/* conserver le ratio des images et empêcher les débordements de boîtes dûs aux border ou padding */
 img {
   height: auto; width: auto;
   -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
   -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
 }

 /* gestion des mots longs */
 textarea, table, td, th, code, pre, samp {
   word-wrap: break-word; /* passage à la ligne forcé */
   -webkit-hyphens: auto; /* césure propre */
   -moz-hyphens: auto;
   hyphens: auto;
 }
 code, pre, samp {
   white-space: pre-wrap; /* passage à la ligne spécifique pour les éléments à châsse fixe */
 }

 /* Passer à une seule colonne (à appliquer aux éléments multi-colonnes) */
 element1, element2 {
   float: none !important;
   width: auto !important
 }

 /* masquer les éléments superflus */
 .hide_mobile {
   display: none !important;
 }

 /* Un message personnalisé */
 body:before {
   content: "Version mobile du site";
   display: block;
   color: #777;
   text-align: center;
   font-style: italic;
 }
}
```

Comment: i am using Eric Meyer's reset css for those kind of css resets, and i found out what was wrong. I was using overflow: hidden; on body and it seems it doesnt work on mobile so that's why the scroll appeared.

Comment: on mobile means : on webkit-based mobile? on Blackberry-based mobile? and so on... each browser add their own css implementation. be careful! Dont forget to close your question if no answer is needed.